Using geom_text or geom_label inside geom_bar
I am plotting the publication of scientific papers on a specific research topic on a timeline. I would like to add author and year to the corresponding rectangles using the "label" variable.

However, geom_text() or geom_label() asks for y asthetic which I don't need using geom_bar(). Is there a workaround?
Here is my code (reproducible example):
year <- c(2012, 2023, 2020, 2023,
          2019, 2017, 2022, 2022,
          2018, 2021, 2016, 2017,
          2019, 2020, 2019, 2022,
          2016, 2021, 2020, 2022,
          2022, 2020, 2015, 2021,
          2021, 2024, 2023)

label <- c('Henry et al. (2012)', 'Breitmayer et al. (2023)', 'Deutsch & Piccirillo (2020)', 'Engelke et al. (2023)',
           'Gerull et al. (2019)', 'Goldberg et al. (2017)', 'Kraft et al. (2022)', 'Lourenco et al. (2022)',
           'Muniandi et al. (2018)', 'Prakash et al. (2021)', 'Probst et al. (2016)', 'Probst et al. (2017)', 
           'Pryss et al. (2019)', 'Pryss et al. (2020)', 'Pryss et al. (2019)', 'Schlee et al. (2022)', 
           'Schlee et al. (2016)', 'Schlee, Simoes & Pryss (2021)', 'Schleicher et al. (2020)', 'Shahania et al. (2022)', 
           'Simoes et al. (2022)', 'Unnikrishnan et al. (2020)', 'Wilson et al. (2015)', 'Lourenco et al. (2021)', 
           'Dode et al. (2021)', 'Engelke et al. (2024)', 'Kleinau et al. (2023)')

topic <- c('feasibility', 'ML', 'review', 'outcome',
           'feasibility', 'feasibility', 'software', 'feasibility',
           'ML', 'ML', 'symptom interaction', 'symptom interaction', 
           'retrospective comparison', 'ML', 'software', 'feasibility', 
           'feasibility', 'outcome', 'ML', 'ML', 
           'symptom interaction', 'ML', 'feasibility', 'feasibility', 
           'retrospective comparison', 'outcome', 'ML')

df_hist <- data.frame(year, label, topic)

ggplot(df_hist, aes(year, fill = topic, group = topic)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#F09EA7", "#F6CA94", "#FAFABE", "#C1EBC0", "#C7CAFF", "#CDABEB", "#F6C2F3")) +
  theme_bw()


Add aes(..., y = 1), then you can set stat = "identity" inside of geom_bar and still get the count and use geom_text for labels:
ggplot(df_hist, aes(year, fill = topic, group = topic, y = 1)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = label),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), angle = 90, size = 3) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#F09EA7", "#F6CA94", "#FAFABE", "#C1EBC0", 
                             "#C7CAFF", "#CDABEB", "#F6C2F3")) +
  theme_bw()



You can use stat_count with a text geom:
ggplot(df_hist, aes(x = year)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = topic, group = topic)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#F09EA7", "#F6CA94", "#FAFABE", "#C1EBC0", "#C7CAFF", "#CDABEB", "#F6C2F3")) +
  stat_count(geom = "text", aes(label = label, x = year, group = label), angle = -90, size = 3, hjust = -0.1) +
  theme_bw()


Another option would be to use the annotate() function.
library(tidyverse)

year <- c(2012, 2023, 2020, 2023,
          2019, 2017, 2022, 2022,
          2018, 2021, 2016, 2017,
          2019, 2020, 2019, 2022,
          2016, 2021, 2020, 2022,
          2022, 2020, 2015, 2021,
          2021, 2024, 2023)

label <- c('Henry et al. (2012)', 'Breitmayer et al. (2023)', 'Deutsch & Piccirillo (2020)', 'Engelke et al. (2023)',
           'Gerull et al. (2019)', 'Goldberg et al. (2017)', 'Kraft et al. (2022)', 'Lourenco et al. (2022)',
           'Muniandi et al. (2018)', 'Prakash et al. (2021)', 'Probst et al. (2016)', 'Probst et al. (2017)', 
           'Pryss et al. (2019)', 'Pryss et al. (2020)', 'Pryss et al. (2019)', 'Schlee et al. (2022)', 
           'Schlee et al. (2016)', 'Schlee, Simoes & Pryss (2021)', 'Schleicher et al. (2020)', 'Shahania et al. (2022)', 
           'Simoes et al. (2022)', 'Unnikrishnan et al. (2020)', 'Wilson et al. (2015)', 'Lourenco et al. (2021)', 
           'Dode et al. (2021)', 'Engelke et al. (2024)', 'Kleinau et al. (2023)')

topic <- c('feasibility', 'ML', 'review', 'outcome',
           'feasibility', 'feasibility', 'software', 'feasibility',
           'ML', 'ML', 'symptom interaction', 'symptom interaction', 
           'retrospective comparison', 'ML', 'software', 'feasibility', 
           'feasibility', 'outcome', 'ML', 'ML', 
           'symptom interaction', 'ML', 'feasibility', 'feasibility', 
           'retrospective comparison', 'outcome', 'ML')

df_hist <- data.frame(year, label, topic) %>%
  arrange(-desc(year)) %>%
  mutate(ypos = c(0.5,
                  0.5,
                  0.5,1.5,
                  0.5,1.5,
                  0.5,
                  0.5,1.5,2.5,
                  0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,
                  0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,
                  0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,
                  0.5,1.5,2.5,
                  0.5)) # position on the y-axis where label should be placed

ggplot(df_hist, aes(year, fill = topic, group = topic)) +
  geom_bar() +
  annotate('text',
           x = df_hist$year,
           y = df_hist$ypos,
           label = label, angle = 90, size = 2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#F09EA7", "#F6CA94", "#FAFABE", "#C1EBC0", "#C7CAFF", "#CDABEB", "#F6C2F3")) +
  theme_bw()


Created on 2024-07-05 with reprex v2.1.0
